# Compare two floats in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, floating-point

How can I compare two floats in JavaScript? Or perhaps a float and an int.

```
if (5 > 4.3.3)

if (5.0 > 5.3)
```

Thankful for all input!

**Update**

I need to for an iPhone app that I am developing in Appcelerator. I need to compare iOS versions and display different content to each. So if a device is running 5.0 and another is running 4.3.3 I need to know the difference in my code.

Comment: 4.3.3 is not a float.

Comment: Try typing `4.3.3` in your calculator ;)

Answer (score 3):

Just like that.

```
if (5.0 > 5.3)
```

In your 1st example you do not have a valid number [`4.3.3`].

Comment: Though it is probably TMI for this question, it should be noted that there are no integers in in Javascript and the specific implementation of floating point causes precision problems.

Comment: I need to for an iPhone app that I am developing in Appcelerator. I need to compare iOS versions and display different content to each. So if a devise is running 5.0 and another is running 4.3.3 I need to know the difference in my code.

Comment: @Jonathan, those are strings then. not integers or floats `4.3.3` is **not** a number

Comment: I shouldn't be rude but this made me laugh

Answer (score 1):

You may use something along the lines of http://maymay.net/blog/2008/06/15/ridiculously-simple-javascript-version-string-to-object-parser/

Basically he uses:

```
function parseVersionString (str) {
    if (typeof(str) != 'string') { return false; }
    var x = str.split('.');
    // parse from string or default to 0 if can't parse
    var maj = parseInt(x[0]) || 0;
    var min = parseInt(x[1]) || 0;
    var pat = parseInt(x[2]) || 0;
    return {
        major: maj,
        minor: min,
        patch: pat
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic comparator can look like:

```
  1. Convert to correct positional structure
  2. Compare lengths
  3. Compare values
```

```js
function compareVer(a, b, sep = '.') {
  // 1. Convert to correct positional structure
  const aP = a.split(sep);
  const bP = b.split(sep);
  // 2. Compare lengths 
  if (aP.length > bP) return 1;
  if (bP.length > aP) return -1;
  for (let i = 0; i < aP.length; ++i) {
    // 3. Compare values
    // You can add necessary type conversions 
    // Ex.: add parseInt, if you want to support `001=1` and not `3f=3f`
    if (aP[i] > bP[i]) return 1;
    if (bP[i] > aP[i]) return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}


console.log(compareVer('5', '4.3.3'));      //  1  gt
console.log(compareVer('5.0.2', '5.0.2'));  //  0  eq
console.log(compareVer('5.0', '5.3'));      // -1  lt
```